# what is the way to install the basic4android

Tags: basic4android

I installed the jre7 and jdk1.7 and android sdk and avd manager perfectly my emulator is working properly but when i run the program which i wrote it is showing

```
Compiling code.                         0.11
Compiling layouts code.                 0.02
Generating R file.                      0.00
Compiling generated Java code.          Error
javac 1.7.0_17
javac: file not found: src\com\empire\designerscripts\*.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

i newly formatted my system  installed these

I am using basic4android in my laptop without any problem but in case of my desktop system it is showing the above error...

Comment: You should post this question in the B4A forums. Erel is quite quick and responding to issues, as are other B4A users, and the fact that many of those users have assisted in debugging the product from the start means they've experienced most issues already. This is really a vendor support question rather than a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood from Erel that this is fixed with Basic4Android v2.50 or above. One can also instead install the latest Java 6 version and use it for compilation.
The use of Java 6 was successful in my case.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem is with the jdk that you are running. Try with jdk1.6.0_25. I use this one and never update this version because the version 7 have some issues with security.